# Process manager issues with zend framework 2

Tags: php, performance, debugging, zend-framework

I am running a website (zf2) which is continuously hitting a very high load on server. When I go and check the process manager to see what part of website is causing so much stress, it always shows me /public/index.php for all php related process.

Is there any way through which I can find which controller and action are being called by which process, so that I can nail down the load issue?

When I restart Apache, it cools down the stress for some time. I am unable to figure out which part of website is creating so much load.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install/configure [ZendDeveloperTools](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools). This is a small module it will allow you to debug certain parts on the ZF2 MVC layer.
Based on its outcome you will be ablto to narrow down if your application has (for example) routing overhead.

On top of ZendDeveloperTools you can install [BjyProfiler](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyProfiler). The package allows you to do database query profiling. If you are using an ORM like [Doctrine](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule), you dont need the BjyProfiler module, the toolbar will show you all your executed queries.

All of the above is for standard debugging. However if you are eager to optimize/debug speed based on your currently deployed framework instance you can do a several more things;

- Events: [ZfSnapEventDebugger](https://github.com/snapshotpl/ZfSnapEventDebugger)
- Configuration (check performance): [ThaConfigalyzer](https://github.com/ThaDafinser/ThaConfigalyzer)
- Used resources (counter): [EdpClassCounter](https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpClassCounter)
- Advanced PHP debuggers: [APD](http://php.net/apd) or [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/)
- Server: add more resources (memory, caching, cpu's,  etc)
- Local and live; compare both environments response times to narrow down hardware issues on the live environment network

Keep in mind, when installing ZendDeveloperTools on your live environment you will have to make sure you display this module contents only for you! (for example; put an `if` statement where  you add your module to active modules (`/config/application.config.php`). If you forget to do so, all of your sensitive configuration is shown on the application (thus the entire world can see it).